# Applying series of conditions to dataframe. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I used to work with np.where function when applying  multiple conditions to dataframe and feel ok in using it.
I would like to improve my code where the same condition is repeated in each set of conditions in np.where and I do not know how to do it in  most simple (clear and concise manner), either using (1) **.loc** or (2) **IF** "condition" **DO** " apply other conditions"

Example:

I need to select only rows where "Date" is under condition (eg. >20200201) and only for these rows, calculate new column, applying another set of different conditions (eg. condition 1: A >20 and B >20; condition 2: A==30 and B==10, condition 3: A==20 and B>=10 etc)

My question what will be **the best way** to make the first selection (Data >20200202)  to not repeat Date>2020201 in every line and avoid this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,3,2,2,3,1,3,2],
           "Date": [20200109, 20200204, 20200307, 20200216, 20200107, 20200108, 20200214, 20200314],
           "A": [20,10,40,40,10,20, 40,30], 
           "B": [20,30,40,50,20, 30, 20, 10]})

df['new']=np.nan
df['new']=np.where((df['Date']>20200201) & (df['A']>20) & (df['B']>20), 'value', df['new'])
df['new']=np.where((df['Date']>20200201) & (df['A']==30) & (df['B']==10), 'value', df['new'])
df['new']=np.where((df['Date']>20200201) & (df['A']==20) & (df['B']>=10), 'value', df['new'])
```

Comment: kindly add expected output ... concrete values for ur conditions

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can use `np.select`:

```
s1 = df.Date <= 20200201
s2 = (df['A'] > 20) & df['B'].gt(20)
s3 = df['A'].eq(30) & df['B'].eq(10)
s4 = df['A'].eq(20) & df['B'].ge(10)

df['new'] = np.select( (s1,s2|s3|s4), (np.nan, 'value'), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   ID      Date   A   B    new
0   1  20200109  20  20    nan
1   3  20200204  10  30    nan
2   2  20200307  40  40  value
3   2  20200216  40  50  value
4   3  20200107  10  20    nan
5   1  20200108  20  30    nan
6   3  20200214  40  20    nan
7   2  20200314  30  10  value
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution, @Quang Hoang. You suggested to define conditions first and then, select those that applicable in each case.
I am still not sure if I can do this way, since I do not how  many conditions will be and how they interact with each other but i like this solution. Thank you !

Comment: @Vero the point is that `s1` is separated from all the other conditions. You can check it with as the first condition, then all the other condition are included in its negates.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not the fastest solution, but its advantage is
**readability** and **easy maintenance** (in the future).

1. Find rows in question using *query* and the indices of these rows:

   ```
   ind = df.query('Date > 20200201 and (A > 20 and B > 20 or '
       'A == 30 and B == 10 or A == 20 and B >= 10)').index
   ```
2. Save new value in new column, in the indicated rows:

   ```
   df.loc[ind, 'new'] = 'value'; df
   ```

Other values in this column remain *NaN*.

If in the future something changes in the above condition, it is quite easy
and intuitive to correct it.

So unless your data volume is very big and the execution time is
prohibitively long, this solution is worth to consider.

Comment: my guts telling me that chaining `and` and `or` without brackets is a very bad idea.

Comment: At least in *query* it is not any problem. But adding parentheses will not harm either. Especially if the reader is not sure about operators precedence.